# Prevent services subdomains from browsing

Tags: debian, security, apache2, internal-dns

I'm facing a problem, and I don't know what are the best practices for it.

I got a VPS hosting multiple services (DNS, Apache and IMAP/SMTP).
The domain is *briffoud.fr* and each service has its subdomain e.g. *smtp.briffoud.fr*.

When I browse to *smtp.briffoud.fr*, for example, it goes the main website, but it shows *smtp.briffoud.fr* in the address bar.

For now, I use this rewriting rule in Apache :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.briffoud.fr/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it is not very "clean".

How can I prevent the browsing of subdomains corresponding to other services, and what is the best practices to do it ? Should it be done with DNS instead ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a default virtual host, which sends 404 HTTP not found to visitors. Default virtual host covers all connections where the requested host does not match an existing virtual host.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427379/apache-default-virtualhost has many options for setting an Apache2 default virtual host.